# How to change JBoss eap 6.1 deployment folder

Tags: deployment, jboss

I'm trying to change deployment folder for JBoss without success. 
Regarding some information which I've found on google I was trying to change `standalone.xml` configuration file. I've added following lines after `<extensions>` node :

> ```
> <system-properties>
> <property name="deploydir" value="/home/Artur"/>
> </system-properties>
> ```

And I've changed `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">` as following:

> ```
>     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
>         <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="deploydir" scan-interval="10000"/>
>     </subsystem>
> ```

I have the following path `/home/Artur/deployments` on my system. 
But when i try to run JBoss server I always get an error :

> 09:05:21,283 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),
>       ("scanner" => "default")
>   ]): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS014847: Could not find a path called 'deployments'

I was trying to configure it with different paths on my system, I was checking also for spelling in every case. But nothing helps. Does anyone have and idea how to properly configure path for deployment folder in JBoss ? (version as in title)

Comment: Please move your solution into an answer, which you can accept after a few days have passed, and thus resolve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I solved this issue. To change deployment directory it's needed to specyify path to this directory in block :

> ```
> <paths>
>   <path name="deploydir" path="/home/Artur"/>
>  </paths>
> ```

instead of

> ```
>   <system-properties>
>     <property name="deploydir" value="/home/Artur"/>
>   </system-properties>
> ```

which I mentioned about earlier. So i conclusion we need to specify `<path>` node in standalone.xml configuration file and change `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">` to point on newly created `path` (in this case to "deploydir")